# TestNG Suite running for Multiple Test

Tags: xml, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am trying to execute following testng Suite.

Below code is for testng.xml

```
<suite name="Suite" parallel="none">
   <test name="Module 1">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.testcases.Class1" />
    </classes>
  </test> 

  <test name="Module 2">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.testcases.Class2" />
    </classes>
  </test> 
</suite>
```

Also, do have the class code snippets as shown below:

```
public class Class 1{
  @Test(dataProvider = "getdata")
    public void DoClass1(Hashtable<String, String> data){
       Some Code
    }
  @DataProvider
    public Object[][] getdata() {
      return TestUtil.getdata(Module, xls);
    }

  @AfterTest
    public void close()
    {
      driver.quit(); //Using to Close the FireFox
    }
```

Similarly I have the Code for Class2

Now When I run the Suite with following steps:

Class 1 - Open Browser
          Navigate

Class 2 - Open Browser
          Navigate

While running the suite Class 1 runs successfully and closes the FireFox Browser.
For Class 2 - Prompts Unable to Open browser.

Please help what needs to be change / update.

Comment: where you're opening the browser in which class

Answer (score 0):

1. parallel="none" is incorrect usage.
2. If you use same "driver" instance for both classes than your session will be ended in your @afterTest.

Answer (score 0):

Put both the classes in a single `<test>` tag.  This way your @AfterTest would be executed only once after both the classes have completed executed.

Or else move your driver quit code to @AfterSuite